# Is this Functional Lipschitz?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E =[a,b]$ be a compact interval and $p =1$. Let $T$ be a bounded linear functional on $L^P(E)$ and let $g$ be a function in $L^q(E)$, where $q$ is the conjugate of $p$. Then define the linear functional $$ T(f) = \int_E g \cdot f $$ for all $f \in L^P(E)$.

I was told that this function $$\Phi(x) = T(\chi_{[a,x)})$$, where $\chi$ is the characteristic function for $[x,a)$, is Lipschitz on $E$. How can I show this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, in general.

As an example let $p > 2$, $E = [0,1]$ and let $g(t) = t^{-1/2}$. The function $\Phi$ can be computed explicitly as
$$\Phi(x) = T(\chi_{[0,x)}) = \int_0^x t^{-1/2} \, dt = 2 \sqrt{x}$$ which is not Lipschitz.

You can, however, show Holder continuity using (unsurprisingly) Holder's inequality.

---

The case $p=1$ is quite trivial. Assume $x<y$. Then $$|\Phi(y) - \Phi(x)| = \left| \int_x^y g \right| \le \int_x^y |g| \le \|g\|_\infty |x-y|.$$

Comment: I am looking for the case in which p =1. I'm sorry if i did not clarify that